# What does 50,000 each on Firebase File Storage Free Plan mean?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

Does it mean each user can only upload only 50,000 files in total? Or does it mean only 50,000 users can upload files simultaneously?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not firebase sales support.

Comment: It means you can upload 50k files and download 50k files, that's 100k in total. If you cross that limit, you should consider upgrading to Flame or Blaze Plan because the moment limit is reached, you won't be able to upload or download any file.

Comment: @MarcB Well [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/) suggests to ask questions on Stack Overflow, probably that's why he came here.

Comment: yes, for programming help. asking what their pricing plans mean is NOT programming.

Comment: @MarcB I agree, this question has nothing to do with programming but the user doesn't know about it, he just came because that page said to do so.

Comment: which doesn't make it any more on-topic for this site. Don't encourage MORE off-topic questions.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Storage offers a free tier that offers the following limits:

- 5GB data storage (total), you'll get capped if you try to store more
- 30GB outgoing bandwidth (per month), your limits are reset after that period
- 50,000 uploads and downloads (per month), again, with limits reset after the month

A single user can use all the resources, or 50,000 users can all upload or download one (small) thing per month. They're just monthly usage quotas, that you can learn more about [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas) (we use the GAE free tier bucket).

Comment: What about the database 1 GB limit? Is that total or resets per month?

Comment: All storage limits are permanent (we won't give you an extra 1GB of storage per month), while other limits are refreshed monthly.